# objective reg:squaredlogerror dos not exist in r implementation of xgboost?

Tags: r, xgboost

I am using the xgboost library in r. My model seems to run fine with the default objective `reg:squarederror`

This runs fine within my code e.g.

```
model_regression = map2(.x = dtrain_regression, .y = nrounds, ~xgboost(.x, nrounds = .y, objective = "reg:squarederror")))
```

[Reading the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), there is another potential objective listed, `reg:squaredlogerror`. I wanted to experiment with this objective:

```
model_regression = map2(.x = dtrain_regression, .y = nrounds, ~xgboost(.x, nrounds = .y, objective = "reg:squaredlogerror")))
```

However, when I run with this variation I get an error message that this objective is unknown.

Is it possible to use the objective `reg:squaredlogerror` within xgboost in r?

Comment: Which version of xgboost?

Comment: 'Package xgboost version 0.90.0.02'

Comment: That's old. It only supports it if the 0.9 doc says it does. Upgrade to the current (1.1.0), and it should work fine. Please confirm so we can close this question.

Comment: Looks like on r, cran only goes up to 0.9 right now https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/index.html

Comment: [The latest xgboost is always available via github for both R and Python](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html). This has been the case for years. Sometimes there is some install pain with xgboost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the latest xgboost. Install it with `install_github`, see the instructions [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html)

(Don't expect CRAN to have the latest version of a package, esp. if under very active development (like xgboost is), it will lag by a release cycle. Generally the latest development build will be on github )

Answer (score 0):

Try using reg:linear as objective, it will work :)